# How to stop service after AsyncTask finished?

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask

I have a service, that requests another class, which launches an AsyncTask

Service->Weather Class->Execute Method->Asynctask->Execute

this is launched in the service by

```
new Weather(this).execute(); // the execute is a method of the class, not of the AsyncTask
```

how do I detect in Service that the AsyncTask finished so I can call stopSelf?

Comment: I don't have a complete answer, therefore just a comment. Can't you use an IBinder in your service and send a message in your onPostExecute() of your AsyncTask.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample

Comment: My service is not using the IBinder stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [stopService(intent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#stopService(android.content.Intent)) in this case.

Comment: Excellent. From @Doc If the service is not running, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

The approach currently employed in our application is to register a single `BroadcastReceiver` against the `android.app.Service` which is set-up to listen for broadcast events fired from the spawned underlying `AsyncTask#onPostExecute`. This is favourable in our scenario since our service spawns three AsyncTasks and we would like to stop the parent service when all three AsyncTasks have completed, i.e. we have three hits against our service level `BroadcastReceiver`.

Thought I'd add this here after I stumbled upon this question long after it was answered but hopefully it may help someone else...